# Calling another function error

Tags: python, function

This is supposed to be a test program on which I can practice python. I defined main and built up the code. When the answer is right, I press 'Y' and it is supposed to jump to the next function which is the next code block after this one ends. The error is get is this:

```
NameError: name 'logic_ques' is not defined.
```

How do I start the next function after I press 'y' and not get an error? Is the problem the order?

```
def main():

    pts = 0
    numberStr = input("Please enter the sum of 251 and 516: \n ")
    num = int(numberStr)
    print ('You have entered: ', num)

    if (num == 767):
        pts += 1
        print ('The answer is correct!')
        print ('You currently have ', pts, 'point(s).')
        continue1 = input('Press any key to see the next question.')
        logic_ques()
    else:
        print ('The answer is not correct.')
        restart = input('The answer is wrong, type Y if you want to restart, and N if you want to exit. \n')
        if (restart == 'y'):
            main()
        else:
            exit()

main()

def logic_ques():

    logicStr = input("Which animal sleeps on legs, not lying down?")
    print ('You have entered the following animal:', logicStr)

    if (logicStr == 'horse'):
        pts += 1
        print ('The asnwer is correct!')
        print ('You currently have ', pts, 'points.')
        continue1 = input('Press any ket to see the next question.\n')
    else:
        print ('The asnwer is not correct!')
        restart1 = input('The answer is wrong, type Y if you want to restart, and N if you want to exit. \n')
        if (restart1 == 'y'):
            logic_ques()
        else:
            exit()
logic_ques()
```

Comment: You call `main` **before** reaching the point of the script at which you define `logic_ques`. Yes, the problem is the order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the problem is the order. You are calling the logic_ques() function in main() before you define it. Simply move definition of logic_ques() above the point where you call main()

Comment: The problem is that, if the answer is wrong and I want to return to the question it is going to return to the beginning where I defined logic_ques() and the script is way under, so basically the program ends.

Comment: If you want to keep asking these questions to the user until they get it wrong, I would use an loop that keeps asking the question until they get it right or enter “N” rather than calling the function again recursively. Other than that, I’m unsure what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Move the definition of logic_ques() before the definition of main()